# Vertical align on image with css

Tags: css, responsive-design

How can I vertical align content inside `absolute div` on image?

http://jsfiddle.net/uxKpn/

Comment: Please incorporate your code into your Q. Links outside of SO can vanish anytime.

Comment: do you want to vertically align the `.article-comments`?

Comment: Yes, i want to verticaly align article-comments?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do this :

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uxKpn/24/)

you nedd to display `.article-comments` as table and make an inner wraper displayed as `table-cell` and set to `vertical-align:middle`.

This solution alows you to vertical-align your content even if it changes (ex: a user posts a comment)

HTML:

```
<div class="picture-comments">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.healthyfoodhouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/5-healthy-breakfasts-for-fat-burning-eggs.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    <div class="article-comments">
        <div class="wrap">
            <h4>45</h4>
            <h4>comments</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.comments -->
</div><!-- picture-comments -->
```

css :

```
.picture-comments {
    position: relative;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

.article-comments {
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display:table;


    h4 {
        font-family: $body-font;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .wrap{
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the picture positioned to absolute and the div to relative.
relative positioned elements always position themselves to the left top corners of the last absolute positioned element.

e.g.

```
img 
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.article-comments 
{
    position:relative;
}
```

then you may be able to vertical align your div over the image!

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle;` on `.picture-comments`.